# Efficient way to replace values in column if part of those values are in predefined lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

So I've actually solved this, but the way I'm doing it may not be the most efficient.

For a column in my database - `Industry` - I want to replace values. If a value contains the word "tech", "technology" or something similar, I want to replace that value with just the word "technology".

I've followed a basic algorithm below using `apply` which basically loops through a predefined list (e.g. `science`) and checks whether any of the values are present in the current `Industry` cell, and replaces if they are.

It then does the same for the next list. I only have two lists so far, but I'll likely have over a dozen once I'm finished.

```
def industry_convert(row):
    
    science = ["research", "science", "scientific", "scientist", "academia", "education", "academic"]
    tech = ["technology", "tech", "software"]

    for v in science:
        if v.lower() in row.Industry.lower():
            row.Industry = "Research, Science, & Education"
            
    for v in tech:
        if v.lower() in row.Industry.lower():
            row.Industry = "Technology"
            
    return row

df = df.apply(industry_convert, axis = 1)
```

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to do this, or if there is a more `pythonic` or `pandas` way of doing it?

EDIT:

This is what some of the Industry column looks like:

```
Industry
Research Scientist
Science: Education
Tech
Technical Assistance
Technology
Medical
Hospitality
```

This what it would look like after applying the code:

```
Industry            
Research, Science, & Education
Research, Science, & Education
Technology
Technology
Technology
Medical
Hospitality
```

Comment: There is certainly a better method but first can you add a sample dataframe?

Comment: I've added an example of what the Industry column looks like

Answer (score 0):

I updated the for loop, in your function:

```py
science = list(map(lambda x:x.lower(),["research", "science", "scientific", "scientist", "academia", "education", "academic"]))
tech = list(map(lambda x:x.lower(),["technology", "tech", "software"]))
def industry_convert(row):
    global science,tech
    


  
     if row.Industry.lower() in science:
          row.Industry = "Research, Science, & Education"
            
    
     if row.Industry.lower() in science:
          row.Industry = "Technology"
            
    return row

df = df.apply(industry_convert, axis = 1)
```

I computed the lists to lower only once, so that it is not recomputed and the computation of the for loop is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use `str.contains` and `.loc` to assign new values.

this will work a number of times faster than looping over each row individually to check. (Which is an anti pattern with regards to the pandas API)

```
science = ["research", "science", "scientific", "scientist", "academia", "education", "academic"]
tech = ["technology", "tech", "software"]
```

---

```
df.loc[df['Industry'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(science)}",regex=True,case=False),
                         'industry_new'] = "Research, Science, & Education"

df.loc[df['Industry'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(tech)}",regex=True,case=False),
                         'industry_new'] = "Technology"


df['industry_new'] = df['industry_new'].fillna(df['Industry'])
```

---

```
print(df)

               Industry                    industry_new
0    Research Scientist  Research, Science, & Education
1    Science: Education  Research, Science, & Education
2                  Tech                      Technology
3  Technical Assistance                      Technology
4            Technology                      Technology
5               Medical                         Medical
6           Hospitality                     Hospitality
```